# Load high-dimensional R dataset into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, r, pandas, rpy2

Some [R datasets](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/00Index.html) can be [loaded into a Pandas DataFrame or Panel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/r_interface.html#transferring-r-data-sets-into-python) quite easily:

```
import pandas.rpy.common as com
infert = com.load_data('infert')
print(infert.head())
```

This appears to work as long as the dimension of the R dataset is <= 3. Higher dimensional datasets print an error message:

```
In [67]: com.load_data('Titanic')
Cannot handle dim=4
```

This error message originates in the [rpy/common.py](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/rpy/common.py#L78) `_convert_array` function.

Sure, it makes sense that Pandas can not directly shoe-horn a 4-dimensional matrix into a DataFrame or Panel, but is there some workaround to load datasets like `Titanic` into a DataFrame (maybe with a hierarchical index)?

Comment: `melt` it first in R, and then load it...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Pandas version 0.13.0 or newer](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/5042), `pandas.rpy.common.load_data` can load higher dimensional datasets such as `Titanic`:

```
import pandas.rpy.common as com
df = com.load_data('Titanic')
print(df.head())
```

yields

```
  Survived    Age     Sex Class value
0       No  Child    Male   1st   0.0
1       No  Child    Male   2nd   0.0
2       No  Child    Male   3rd  35.0
3       No  Child    Male  Crew   0.0
4       No  Child  Female   1st   0.0
```

Answer (score 6):

Using @joran's very helpful suggestion, after installing the `reshape` package with

```
% sudo R
R> install.packages('reshape')
```

I managed to load the `Titanic` dataset into a Pandas DataFrame with:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.rpy.common as com
import rpy2.robjects as ro

r = ro.r
r('library(reshape)')
df = com.convert_robj(r('melt(Titanic)'))
print(df.head())
```

which printed

```
  Class     Sex    Age Survived  value
1   1st    Male  Child       No      0
2   2nd    Male  Child       No      0
3   3rd    Male  Child       No     35
4  Crew    Male  Child       No      0
5   1st  Female  Child       No      0
```

Comment: Glad it worked. FYI, **reshape** is the old version. Might be worth using **reshape2** instead.